# Wanting a css animation to last forever in one direction

Tags: css, css-animations

Hello I'm trying to make a stock/crypto finance ticker that moves at the top of a react application.

[image]

It takes data form an API and generates 100 individual items. This works fine and even works well however when it gets to the end of the css animation it just resets to the beginning of the list and starts over as it should. However I want this animation to keep going in that direction forever because I'll be deleting the beginning items from the ticker container div and appending new updated ones at the end of the ticker. This would work fine if the ticker's animation didn't reset.

So in short I would just like this css animation to keep going no matter what.

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes ticker {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}
@keyframes ticker {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    visibility: visible;
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
  }
}
.ticker {
  background-color: #131722;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
.ticker .ticker-inner {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 100%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-name: ticker;
  animation-name: ticker;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 800s;
  animation-duration: 800s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add     `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to achieve this.

```
.ticker .ticker-inner {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 100%;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  animation:ticker linear 1s infinite forwards;
  -webkit-animation:ticker linear 1s infinite forwards;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir I was looking at sooooooooo many articles/overflow questions but couldn't find the answer!

Comment: you are welcome  :)